# PowerShell, PSCustomObject, array format issue

Tags: arrays, powershell, pscustomobject, veeam

I am trying to create array made by `PSCustomObject` elements, but having some issues with it. Here is the simplified example of the code I have:

```
$FineData = @()

foreach ($Session in $Sessions) {  

        $Job = Get-VBRTaskSession -Session $Session 

        $Result = [pscustomobject]@{ 

                Id = $job.Id.Guid                       
        }

        $FineData += $Result
}

$FineData
```

The format it returns:

```
Id                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
{19ea68a7-f2c3-4429-bc46-a87b4a295105, 3ebf8568-10ce-4608-bbb2-c80d06874173, 2ec28852-3f5e-477d-8742-872863e41b6d}
```

The format I want:

```
Id             : 19ea68a7-f2c3-4429-bc46-a87b4a295105

Id             : 3ebf8568-10ce-4608-bbb2-c80d06874173

Id             : 2ec28852-3f5e-477d-8742-872863e41b6d
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: += kills puppies

Comment: You could just use a calculated expression: `(Get-VBRTaskSession -Session $Session).Id.Guid | Select @{N='Id';E={$_}} | FL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like your `Get-VBRTaskSession` could be returning more than one object, hence an inner loop is required:

```
$FineData = foreach ($Session in $Sessions) {  
    foreach($guid in (Get-VBRTaskSession -Session $Session).Id.Guid) {
        [pscustomobject]@{ 
            Id = $guid
        }
    }
}

$FineData
```

You can then pipe `$FineData` to [`Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-list?view=powershell-7.3) if you want it to be displayed as a list in your console:

```
$FineData | Format-List
```

As aside, adding to a fixed collection should be avoided, see this answer for details: [Why should I avoid using the increase assignment operator (+=) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708578/why-should-i-avoid-using-the-increase-assignment-operator-to-create-a-colle).